# Download Link in a Form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I tried to search and locate information on this topic and was unsuccessful. I would like to add a link to my form that allows a user to download a CSV file for completion of required data. How do I do this in Cognito?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not offer a way to upload files to a Cognito Form, that the end user could then download. You can include links to files that you would like to have your end user download. The file would need to be hosted in your website and the link could then be included in your Cognito Form.